# XStream - loading custom XML

Tags: java, xml, xstream, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to load an XML file of the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MyCompany>
    <Record>
        <Surname>
            Bird
        </Surname>
        <Given1>
            Andrew
        </Given1>
        <ID>
            225958
        </ID>
        <BirthDate>
            260391
        </BirthDate>
        <PeerYear>
            2009
        </PeerYear>
        <Title>
        </Title>
        <Preferred>
            Andrew
        </Preferred>
        <Given2>
            Macarthur
        </Given2>
        <CountryOfBirthCode>
            AUS
        </CountryOfBirthCode>
        <NationalityCode>
        </NationalityCode>
        <OccupCode>
            Retired
        </OccupCode>
        <Suburb>
            Metung
        </Suburb>
        <State>
            Vic
        </State>
        <PostCode>
            3904
        </PostCode>
        <CountryCode>
            AUS
        </CountryCode>
        <Phone>
    </Record>
```

I try to READ, not write to that format, so I've set aliases as:

```
m_XStream.alias("MyCompany", MyCompany.class);
m_XStream.alias("Record", Record.class);
```

Where Mycompany is:

```
public class Mycompany 
{
    @XStreamImplicit
    public List<Record> Records = new ArrayList<Record>();
}
```

And Record is a class with public member variables ala:

```
public class Record
{
public String ID;
public String Surname;
}
```

When I try to read from above XML, it doesn't read anything into MyCompany.Records member variable.

**What would be the correct way to read XML like that and, also, how to ignore elements for which member variable is not present?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To process the `@XStreamImplicit` annotation in `MyCompany` you need to call this first:

```
m_XStream.processAnnotations(MyCompany.class);
```

Or instead of the annotation you can do this:

```
m_XStream.addImplicitCollection(MyCompany.class, "Records");
```

Comment: Thanks WhiteFang34, I've already doing it via:
m_XStream.alias("MyCompany", MyCompany.class);
m_XStream.alias("Record", Record.class);
m_XStream.addImplicitCollection(MyCompany.class, "Records");

I've perused http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=371569 for reference, too.

Comment: I managed to have it parse the XML, however the extended XML contains elements that do not exist in Record class. What is the way to ignore those elements? Custom XStream deserializer?

Comment: This article might help: [Omit Unexpected XML Elements With XStream](http://pvoss.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/xstream/). Or you could just add the member fields and not use them.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it already, however it reports that "Ignoring the fieldName Record as it must be new." when doing 
System.out.println("Ignoring the fieldName " + fieldName + " as it must be new.");
after if statement

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by using @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="Record") instead of m_XStream.addImplicitCollection(MyCompany.class, "Records", Record.class)